# Start onActivityResult after the completion of loop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have a `buttonClickListener` that is intended to uninstall multiple apps so I've run a for loop for that and I want to start `onActivityResult` after the completion of all uninstallation process. SO far `onActivityResult` runs after each uninstallation. I want only one `onActivityResult` at the end. Is there any way I can do that?

```
 btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
                    AllApps singleApp= appList.get(i);
                    if (singleApp.isSelected()) {
                        String app_pkg_name = singleApp.getPackageName();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is the onActivityResult:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE){

          //things to do 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First , is not possible but you can just simply execute `onActivityResult` for the last command and in order to do that, you need to have a filtered list first

```
btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // filter selected apps
    List<AllApps> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(AllApps app : appList){
        if(app.isSelected())
            temp.add(app);
    }

    // invoke app uninstallations
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size()-1; i++) {
        startActivity(uninstallAppIntent(temp.get(i)));
    }
    // invoke get result for last entry
    startActivityForResult(uninstallAppIntent(temp.get(temp.size()-1)), UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});

// to avoid code duplicity
Intent uninstallAppIntent(Allapps singleApp){
    String app_pkg_name = singleApp.getPackageName();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
    return intent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

You can put variable `i` on data of intent and check if `i==app.size()` on `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Its A Simple use case of a `If` statement . you can take a `boolean` or just check appropriate condition. Checkout the code below .

```
btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AllApps singleApp=null;
            for (int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
                if (appList.get(i).isSelected()) {
                    singleApp=appList.get(i);
                }
            }
            if(singleApp!=null){
                String app_pkg_name = singleApp.getPackageName();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    });
```

**NOTE** IF `appList` contains multiple selected items then the last indexed item will be used . In this case if you want first selected item the you should `break` the loop .

Comment: I have provided the logic only . i don't think multiple apps can be uninstalled at once . So it should be done one by one .

Comment: I think it would a good idea to add the logic to accomplish the task to keep only the last selected object for result